# concatenate xml in c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have xml stored in a variable:

```
<response>
    <patientmetadata>
        <Barcode>String</Barcode>
        <PatientID>0</PatientID>
        <PatientFirstName>String</PatientFirstName>
        <PatientLastName>String</PatientLastName>
        <PatientDOB>String</PatientDOB>
        <PhysicianID>0</PhysicianID>
        <DocumentDate>String</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentSubject>String</DocumentSubject>
        <SystemName>String</SystemName>
        <PageCount>0</PageCount>
        <ErrorMessage>String</ErrorMessage>
    </patientmetadata>
</response>
```

and I got another piece of xml :

```
<filenames>
    <filename newfilename="text" oldfilename="text"/>
    <filename newfilename="text" oldfilename="text"/>
    <filename newfilename="text" oldfilename="text"/>
    <filename newfilename="text" oldfilename="text"/>
</filenames>
```

How do I concatenate them such that the filename node is placed underneath the `PatientMetaData' tag.

Comment: I would write code for it. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: I am new to xml  related things. If you could, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Ninja, I would recommend to read what/how to ask here. You are not looking for help, your are looking for someone to do your work for you.

Comment: Ninja, you really need to try on your own.  Then come and let us know what you tried and what your results were.  Some here are more helpful than others, but you have to at least meet us halfway.

Comment: @EZI WDS, You are correct! I was in a hurry and I guess that triggered me to take the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and it worked for me.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData[0]);// xmlData[0] holds the xml tag.               
            doc.Element("documentservice").Element("postreggieheader").Element("response").Element("patientmetadata").AddAfterSelf(XElement.Parse(PostReggieHeaderResponse)); //postReggieHeaderResponse Variable holds the filename XElement.
```